# Why does GDM start in TTY2 and TTY7

Tags: ubuntu, gnome3, tty, gdm3

I have Ubuntu 15.04 and GNOME 3.16 installed.

This PPAs are enabled:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu vivid main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu vivid main
```

Interestingly, GDM runs in TTY1 and TTY7. Is there a way to fix this? I would like that GDM runs only in TTY7.

Comment: This depends on your login manager, not the window manager.

Comment: @smpl My login manager is GDM3.

Comment: Duplicated on Ask Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/612450/

Comment: @JdeBP, yes, see the answer. And than vote for deletion. :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/613210/367165) response, I have done the following and it works.

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm/gdm.conf
```

In this file, I added the following line.

```
FirstVT=7
```

> In `/etc/gdm/gdm.conf` you can set what the 1st terminal should be the
>   graphical interface. `FirstVT=7` will make GDM check tty7 first (by
>   the way: this could mean it ends up on tty8, tty9 if these are enabled
>   and tty7 is not free.
>
> If this is inactive in `/etc/gdm/gdm.conf` it will probably randomly
>   start with tty1 and if that is active (ie. a terminal session is open)
>   it will pick tty2 and so on.

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/613210/367165)

Comment: When I do this, all I get is gnome-shell running it tty7 and tty8.

Comment: @sencer I will check this, tomorrow.

Comment: @sencer Hmm, not here. I have only TTY7.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks anyway. I downgraded to 3.14 for now.